# Deleting textures in opengl

Tags: c++, windows, opengl, textures

Do I have to delete all the textures I created (using glDeleteTextures) before the program exists, or does OpenGL delete the textures by himself?

Comment: I'm not familiar with the guarantees of OpenGL on releasing texture resources - but it is never a bad idea to clean up after yourself.  Considering that this is a C++ question, textures wrapped up in a class using [RAII](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_Acquisition_Is_Initialization) is a good way to go here.

Comment: http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glDeleteTextures.xml

Comment: AFAIK - any unused textures will definitely get swapped out of the working set pretty soon, but will most likely not be cleaned up till the process exits.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Depending on what manages your OpenGL context, you may not need to delete the textures. For an example, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2034272/1272627).

There does seem to be consensus, though, that it is good to clean up after yourself, but be careful when using C++ RAII to do so!  If a C++ object that manages an OpenGL object via RAII is created or destroyed without an OpenGL context, undefined behavior will occur.

**See: [The Object Oriented Language Problem](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Common_Mistakes#The_Object_Oriented_Language_Problem)**

The OpenGL API and OpenGL objects don't map intuitively to C++ OOP principles.

Answer (score 2):

OpenGL resources are frees implicitly once all contexts with access to them are destroyed. OpenGL contexts of a process get destroyed when the client terminates; however in the case of indirect GLX context objects may be shared among X11 clients, so they may be freed only after the last client with access to them terminates.

Nevertheless it's always a good practice to clean up after yourself.