# Not deleting texture memory in opengl

Tags: opengl, memory-management, drivers

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Deleting textures in opengl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11958298/deleting-textures-in-opengl)

If I have texture memory allocated on the graphic card and I choose not to delete it when the application exits, can I rely on the opengl drivers/operating system to delete it for me?

Comment: Why would you choose not to delete memory that you have allocated?

Comment: I have some problem with the glContext but that´s another problem

Comment: Then this is not an answer to my question :-)

Comment: This seems to be a duplicate question, see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11958298/1272627)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OpenGL resources are frees implicitly once all contexts with access to them are destroyed. OpenGL contexts of a process get destroyed when the client terminates; however in the case of indirect GLX context objects may be shared among X11 clients, so they may be freed only after the last client with access to them terminates.

Nevertheless it's always a good practice to clean up after yourself.

**Note : From datenwolf.(Not from me)**

Comment: You really should give better attribution for this - this is [not your answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11959785/1272627).

Comment: @Kaiged I know.And I have said it is from the user named datenwolf.