# Android NDK NativeActivity Memory Management Needed?

Tags: android, c++, opengl-es, android-ndk, native-activity

I'm using `NativeActivty` with native_app_glue to program an `OpenGL` game for Android. It is hard to determine when is the best time to delete heap allocated objects and objects allocated by `OpenGL`.

In the NDK's `NativeActivity` sample they don't seem to delete objects after they are done with them. Right now I delete my objects with two delete functions: one for `OpenGL` objects and a regular one. I split them up because it seems only the event handling thread can delete `OpenGL` objects. Regular objects I allocate are deleted by the normal delete function.

When the user presses the back button and comes back to the app, the `OpenGL` resources are deleted and the app crashes (although I would think they should be reallocated by `APP_CMD_INIT_WINDOW`). This causes me to wonder if I should be deleting objects at all because it appears I should not delete `OpenGL` objects.

Are we supposed to delete heap allocated objects with the NDK. I understand that NDK apps are still sandboxed and have a `JVM` process, does this take car of memory management?

EDIT:
Another instance of my application crashing is when objects are deleted when a game state finishes. For example going from the actual game to the menu. Upon going back to the game the application crahses, even though the objects are reallocated. It only seems to work once.

Comment: You could use smart pointers and stop worrying about memory management? Boost smart pointers work well on Android. For OpenGL part, deleting context should handle deleting OpenGL objects.

Comment: So I shouldn't bother calling functions like glDeleteTextures() and glDeleteBuffers()? And deleting heap allocated objects (both with or without boost) is necessary?

Comment: Check this thread for deleting objects on OpenGL side: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11958298/deleting-textures-in-opengl If you use smart pointers from Boost, you don't care about deleting them. When their references hit 0, they are automatically deleted like the objects declared on stack. That's why they are called smart pointers.

Comment: OK, more explanation: When you hit back button, the OpenGL context is deleted, in this case EGL Context of course, so that all resources declared on OpenGL like textures, buffers etc. also get deleted. When you get back to the OpenGL window, you should create EGL context once again, then reallocate all OpenGL objects so that your app won't crash. As for heap objects, you could delete them manually as you already do or instead of using regular pointers, you could use smart pointers, either from Boost or any other implementation, so that you altogether stop worrying about micro memory management

Comment: I'd rather not use boost as I try to keep my dependencies low. Right now the problem seems to be on the reallocation of objects, for some reason they still seem to be null pointers despite reallocating. However this works on a similar desktop application. It has something to do with android. Thanks for clearing up OpenGL objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out the application crashing was never due to the deletion of heap allocated objects or OpenGL objects. Some pointers that were deleted but still contained in a vector were the cause of the problem. However it appears there is nothing wrong with deleting objects with the NDK.